# Full-Calendar is not working, fullCalender is undefined error

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, next.js

I have recently got into nextjs and I want to use Full-calendar for react, and it is not working, it keeps on saying I fullCalendar is not defined. I think the reason is because it is rendered from the server, and jquery is not recognized, is there any way I can do this?

```
    Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26051:19)
    at $.fullCalendar.version (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26028:37)
    at Object.map../af (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26037:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:25910:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:41903:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
    at C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:76:18
    at C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:79:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:3:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jarka\OneDrive\Desktop\hr-website\hr-next-graphql\next\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to upgrade to FullCalendar V4 as it does not depend on jQuery making it easy to integrate with React. It also has an [official FullCalendar React component](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react) that has been released recently.

Then for the FullCalendar React component docs, you may refer [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react).

For integrating FullCalendar with Next.js, I have written an article on [how to use FullCalendar in Next.js](https://www.davidangulo.xyz/how-to-use-fullcalendar-in-next-js/). You might want to read about it.

I hope this helps.